IKPY Smooth Motion: Inverse Kinematics using Quintic Trajectory
I'm a student part of a team working on a 3D Printed Humanoid based of the Poppy Open Source Project. We are looking into incorporating the IKPY library for both inverse kinematics of the arms and feet. We have created a program that calculates the quintic trajectory with each way point we calculate the inverse kinematics using IKPY to determine the angles for the motors. An issue we are running into is that for each inverse kinematics calculation it does not take the previous into account meaning that it might create erratic movement. Is there any way we could change the library so that it takes the previous angle into account and movement becomes smooth?
We have try to run it as is, but we are getting erratic movements at some points
